# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file: Python

Tags: python

I Created this code but i keep getting returned the error: `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file` What can I do to correct this mistake?

```
def eightBitStrings(n):
    if n > 0:
        #Assign variable to reference the name of the file... This shall be called EightBits...
        eightBits = "eightBits.txt"
        #Open file above
        outputFile = open(eightBits, "w")
        #Track the refrencenumber of values that we generate. 
        #As we generate values, we will decrement the value of counter
        counter = 0
        #As long as counter is LESS than n, we will need more numbers
        # Input random number, convert it to a string and then write it to the file on its own line
        #Add 1 to the counter since have generated a number
        
        while (counter < n):
            randomNumber = int(random.random() * 1001)
            outputFile.write(str(randomNumber) + "\n")
            counter = counter + 1
            outputFile.close()
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Please accept the edit proposed by Subbu VidyaSekar that will make your code easier to read. In essence, you should _either_ (1) prepend each line of code with _additional_ 4 spaces, _\*or\*_ (2) put your code in between a pair of three backticks ( ``` ) on their own lines.

Comment: You're closing the file in a loop... It only needs to be closed once...

Answer (score 3):

In your `while` loop you are closing the file, and then again trying to write it.
Close the file after the loop ends

```py
def eightBitStrings(n):
    if n > 0:
        #Assign variable to reference the name of the file... This shall be called EightBits...
        eightBits = "eightBits.txt"
        #Open file above
        outputFile = open(eightBits, "w")
        #Track the number of values that we generate. 
        #As we generate values, we will decrement the value of the counter
        counter = 0
        #As long as counter is LESS than n, we will need more numbers
        # Input random number, convert it to a string and then write it to the file on its own line
        #Add 1 to the counter since have generated a number
        
        while (counter < n):
            randomNumber = int(random.random() * 1001)
            outputFile.write(str(randomNumber) + "\n")
            counter = counter + 1
        outputFile.close()
```